# Printing bit fields from integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm supposed to extract 10 fields of given widths from a 32-bit integer.

For example, if the given width is 2, then I need to extract the 2 left-most bits of the integer and print their integer value.

Here is the code I have right now,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAnswer(int width[]);

int main(){
    int width[10] = {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2};
    printAnswer(width);
}

void printAnswer(int width[]){
    unsigned int value = 0xCAFEBABE;
    char mask;
    int totalWidth = 0;
    int L; // left
    int R; // right

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        L = 31 - totalWidth; // left end of width
        R = L - width[i]; // right end of width
        totalWidth = totalWidth + width[i];

        // creating a mask to capture bits in range
        mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << totalWidth;

        printf("%d ", (value & mask) >> totalWidth);

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The output I'm getting right now is, 0000000004, which makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the `totalWidth`, since it's not initialized to zero for every entry of for the loop. Could you explain what the variables `totalWidth`, `R`, `L` mean by an example? Also, ging an example of expected output for sample `value` and `width` would be helpful.

Comment: Why `31`? Certainly you are making an assumption about `int`.  If you want a 32-bit integer, use type `int32_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution is an overkill, using left shift, right shift and masking. You can simplify it.

By using left shift and right shift only.

```
void printAnswer(int width[]){
    unsigned int value = 0xCAFEBABE, masked;
    int totalWidth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        masked = value << totalWidth; //get rid of the unwanted left bits
        totalWidth += width[i];
        masked >>= (32 - width[i]); //move the needed bits to the right
        printf("%u ", masked);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Now, let's see the output.

```
6 5 7 7 5 7 5 3 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in extracting the bits originates in types mismatch.
How are you expecting to extract, say, 28th bit from an unsigned integer multiplying to the 8-bit char?

So, first of all **make the mask to be unsigned integer**.
Next, I believe you need to shift your mask to **the 31-totalWidth**, not totalWidth in  `mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << totalWidth;`. As you wrote: "2 left most".

Comment: "make the mask to be unsigned integer" --> then use `unsigned` math as in `mask = (1u << (L - R + 1) - 1) << totalWidth;`  (Notice the `u`)